# Mono ORM that works with PostgreSQL?

Tags: .net, postgresql, mono, orm

I've been trying to find a decent ORM that works with both Mono and PosgreSQL.

Does anyone know of such an ORM?

Answer (score 5):

Any ORM worth its salt should be able to handle PostgreSQL.

NHibernate is a .NET ORM that sprang from Hibernate, a Java-based ORM that handles PostgreSQL quite nicely.  I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Mono includes [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) project. This ORM supports all major relational databases however it's not a stable release yet.

**Edit**

Since version [2.11.3](http://www.mono-project.com/EntityFramework) mono also includes [entity framework support](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Aug-13.html).